# What sound effect is it that plays in Naruto ep: 39 at approx 6:32?

Tags: naruto

This is a common sound effect used in anime to indicate sudden realization often paired with widened eyes and a beam striking through his/her head. I don't know what it's called.  I checked on the internet as much as I could and even looked through soundeffects fandom, but I couldn't find it because I don't know what it's called! Halp.

Thanks